# How should the code for a program outputting to command line be tested/designed?

Tags: design, python, unit-testing

Imagine a program similar to this in Python:

```
import subprocess

class Example():

    _cmd_args = (['ls', '-a', '/usr/bin/'], ['ls', '-al', '/usr/local/bin/'])
    _default_args = 0

    def init(self):
        pass

    def run_ls_command(self):
        p = subprocess.Popen(self.get_command(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = p.communicate()
        return err

    def get_command(self):
        return self._cmd_args[self._default_args]

    def set_args(self, args):
        self._default_args = args

    def do_magical_stuff(self):
        #do some stuff
        self._default_args = 0
        self.run_ls_command()
```

This is a simple example - but imagine a program where the primary "interactions" will be through executing commands through subprocess against the host operating system.

The specific commands and arguments will be constructed as the result of a variety of other configurations and the state of the program at the given time.

**The above code is horribly not testable.**

It seems like it might be best to design it in such a way to have objects like:

```
class MyArgs():

    def __init__(self, _cmd, _cmd_args, _cmd_path):
        self.cmd = _cmd
        self.cmd_args = _cmd_args
        self.cmd_path = _cmd_path

    #more manipulation methods

    def get_command(self):
        return ([self.cmd, self.cmd_args, self.cmd_path])
```

and

```
class Example():

    args = MyArgs()

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run_ls_command(self):
        print self.get_command()
        p = subprocess.Popen(self.get_command(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = p.communicate()
        return err

    def set_args(self, c, a, p):
        #this would be more complicated logic in future and likely not just one method
        self.args.set_args(c,a,p)

    def get_command(self):
        return self.args.get_command()
```

I would then be able to test that `MyArgs.get_command()` works correctly, directly on the class itself, for its given inputs (especially since I doubt I would be constructing a single "set all variables" actual command).

That would allow me to modify my tests against `Example` to primarily test what `Example.get_command()` returns whatever other manipulations would be happening to Example.

This is still not great to me, since I'm testing what should otherwise be private members - other than for testing, `get_command` should be private.

I am primarily intending to test that the right commands are triggered - **not** whether they execute successfully. So for example, if a user passes in `['ls', '-a', '/a/dir/that/does/not/exist']` I do not care at this point that the `ls` will fail - I want to validate the resulting command (actually executing the commands will take longer than I want to do for the unit test suite). Knowing in this case that the `Popen` attempted `ls -a /a/dir/that/does/not/exist` is sufficient.

Is there a better way to design this architecture to facilitate testability?

Comment: Not sure if this can be applied to Python, but in C++ my goto answer would be to write all the code so that it accepts an `istream` and/or `ostream` as parameters, then have the real code pass in `stdin`/`stdout` and the test code pass in some `std::stringstreams` that it can assert on afterward.

Comment: Do you actually want to call `subprocess.Popen` during the test or not?

Comment: @null I don't care if it's _technically_ not called, but I want to know that it WAS called (if it's a mocked or patched somehow that'd be fine too). Maybe I could simply patch the call to somehow return the arguments it's called with?

Comment: @enderland I'm not sure I understand why you want to test what `Popen` does and if it concatenates the list of string correctly. That's part of the standard library and should be considered to be working fine, no?

Comment: @null sorry, I mean I want to validate the text sent to `Popen` -- whether that is a mocked Popen or an actual Popen with output redirected to some other stream (like Ixrec's suggestion) does not matter. Or some other option. However, I would like to avoid actually executing the command with `Popen` as the commands are somewhat time consuming to run.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. The culprit for me is the requirement of privacy for the command data. But at the same time, there should be a publicly decidable (test or release code) way on how that data is used. Even if you pass it a stream (from outside/public) that it can write itself to, you'd still expose the private data publicly. I don't know how (if) these two requirements can be fullfilled at the same time. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, what you want to verify is that `subprocess.Popen` gets called with the right arguments. To do that, you need a testing seam at the boundary between `Example` and the call to `subprocess.Popen`, so that you can replace `Popen` in your tests with a mock.

I am not familiar enough with python to know if you can directly mock `Popen`, but if you can't then it is easy enough to write a small wrapper class that you inject into `Example`. The production version of this wrapper just blindly passes everything through to `Popen`, while in your tests you can use a mock version that allows you to verify that the right arguments are passed.

The wrapper class should be simple/stupid enough that a simple code review can prove that there are no bugs in the wrapper itself, so that you don't need to write tests for that.